# Passing parameters to do not work for module exports

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to pass a parameter to another module then call a function from that module (Node.js ver 6.11):

```
//app.js *********
myService = require(‘./lib.js’)(“Hello World”);
myService.printMessage();


//lib.js **********
var msgToPring;
module.exports = function libService(msg) {
    msgToPring = msg;

    function printMessage(){
        console.log(msgToPring);
    }
}
```

when I run program it fails in app.js in "second" line:

```
Cannot read property 'printMessage' of undefined
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: 1. `myService` is not an object is a function, 2. the return value of libService should be an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`libService` should return an object

```
module.exports = function libService( msg ) {
    let msgToPrint = msg;
    return {
        printMessage() {
            console.log(msgToPrint);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in this case will printMessage() function be able to access other internal functions of libService? Let's say pringMessage() calls another func() within libService() function. So if I call pringMessage() from app.js won't it fail?

Comment: you will use the `this` keyword to access the methods

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. You've structured your library as a function rather than as an object, class, or constructor. `printMessage` can't be referenced outside of `libService`.
2. You should treat the import line as a declaration, and call the function separately later.

   ```
   //app.js *********
   myService = require(‘./lib.js’);
   myService("Hello World");


   //lib.js **********
   var msgToPring;
   module.exports = function libService(msg) {
     msgToPring = msg;

     function printMessage(){
       console.log(msgToPring);
     }
     printMessage(msgToPring);
   }
   ```

If you want, you could move the `printMessage` declaration outside of the libService function.